# JSON Serialization failing for SwiftyJSON Objects

Tags: swift, dictionary, swifty-json

I'm trying to get a json structure like this:

```
{
"settings": [
{"value": 1, "tag": "active"}, 
{"value": 1, "tag": "active"}
]
}
```

I set up a playground with SwiftyJSON and wrote the following test:

```
let ele : [String:JSON] = ["tag" : "active", "value" : 1]
let ele2 : [String:JSON] = ["tag" : "active", "value" : 1]

let eleJSONArray = [ele, ele2]

let parameters : [String:Any] = JSON(["settings":eleJSONArray]).dictionaryObject!
print(parameters)
try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
```

But I get a serialization error as if one of the element is invalid:

```
["settings": [["value": 1, "tag": active], ["value": 1, "tag": active]]]
2017-06-22 15:37:59.078 TestPlayground[57075:19147452] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'
```

Can you point me to where the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are annotating the wrong type, both dictionaries are `[String:Any]`

```
let ele : [String:Any] = ["tag" : "active", "value" : 1]
let ele2 : [String: Any] = ["tag" : "active", "value" : 1]
```

Basically you cannot serialize `JSON` objects with `JSONSerialization` unless you let `SwiftyJSON` do the job.

Side-note: Do not *print pretty* if the JSON is sent to a server. The server doesn't care about text formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong types for your dictionaries, it should be `Any` instead of `JSON` since the value is `Any` and not a JSON.

Correct syntax will be `[String:Any]` for your dictionaries.

```
let ele : [String:Any] = ["tag" : "active", "value" : 1]
let ele2 : [String:Any] = ["tag" : "active", "value" : 1]
```

And now you should be able to get your values through:

```
let tag = ele["tag"] // active
```